# Issue displaying Images from website using Regex

Tags: python, regex

Im currently trying to scrape a website for all images found. My code successfully displays all images including .jpg, .bmp & .gif. However it also displays the height of these images as well. I was wondering how I could change my code to remove the height of the image from the output as well as tidying up the output providing just the clean links as shown in the attachment. Below I have attached both a link showing my codes output as well as my current code below. I have also attached what my ideal output would be. Thanks for any help, appreciated!

My Code Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eferl.jpg

Output I am looking for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RytX4.jpg

```
files = re.findall(r'\<img .*\=.*', page.decode())
files.sort()
print (f'\n [+] {len(files)} IMAGES FOUND:\n')
for file in files:
    print(file)
```

Comment: So your desired output would just remove the height="250" but leaves everything else? (in that one example that is)

Comment: Apologies, I have edited my answer slightly. So its easier to understand. I have now attached an Ideal Output I am looking for below my current output. Thanks Again :)!

Comment: Is Regex a requirement for your solution?

Comment: Not a requirement however heavily preferred as I am also scraping different information from this website and have used only regex so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract image `src` directly

```
>>> images = ['<img src="demo.jpg" height=12>', '<img src="demo2.jpg" height=500>']
>>> for image in images:
        print(re.search(r'<img[^>]*src="([^"]*)"', image).group(1))

demo.jpg
demo2.jpg
```

If your input is all `string`, you may use `findall` and then iterate over it

```
>>> images = '''<img src="demo.jog" height=12> <img src="demo.jog" height=500>'''
>>> res = re.findall(r'<img[^>]*src="([^"]*)"', images)
>>> for img in res:
        print(img)
demo.jpg
demo2.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Im going to test it now and ill get back to you!

Comment: You can try my second approach since your input seems all string

Comment: Thanks just went through this and this is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not exactly the best tool to parse HTML or XML data, and BeautifulSoup is much more efficient and simple there. You could do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...    
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.decode(), 'html.parser')
files = [ i.get("src") for i in soup.findAll('img') ]  # get the src attribute for all img tags
files.sort()
print (f'\n [+] {len(files)} IMAGES FOUND:\n')
for file in files:
    print(file)
```

That way, the HTML is effectively parsed and only real tags are returned.

Comment: Yeah I was looking into BeautifulSoup earlier, thanks for the suggestion will have another look at it :)